# How to reopen a closed Sharepoint web-part without the ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

We have a set of dashboards which have just 1 web part each.  While updating one of these, I went into Web Part Maintenance and closed the only web part.  According to several sources (like this [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMY9BUxljmc) video), all I need to do is go into the ribbon to edit the page and re-add the closed web part.

Unfortunately, for unknown reasons (I didn't make them), that entire ribbon isn't visible on these pages. How do I re-enter editing mode so that I re-add my web part?

Comment: Dear down-voter, it doesn't help to down vote a question without an explanation.  I'm listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove wrong webpart. Just add ?contetns=1 to the .aspx-page url.
Some helpfull link are described there:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/05/23/famous-sharepoint-urls-amp-locations.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ruslan.  I actually needed the `?ToolPaneView=2` flag to open the page in Edit mode.  Your link has been bookmarked.